# CSS not working in mobile view in WordPress even after setting viewport before <head> tag

Tags: wordpress, responsive, viewport, meta

I am developing a WordPress theme for a consulting company. But, I am having problem with the CSS for the mobile devices.

I have included `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">` before the ending of `<head>` tag. When I check the responsiveness in the chrome console, I get the desired result but when I test it in the real mobile device the responsiveness is not displaying any of my media query that I have written for every div. I have the following code for the `css` and `js` in my `functions.php`:

```
function my_script_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_style('myStyle', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/main_styles.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('news', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/news.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('newsResponsive', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/news_responsive.css', array(), '1.0', 'all'); //File that contains media query code for news page.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontAwesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owlCarousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.theme.default.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/animate.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'video', get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugins/video-js/video-js.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css',false,'1.1','all'); //File that contains media query code for whole website.
    wp_enqueue_script('jQuery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('popper', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap4/popper.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('greensockTween', get_template_directory_uri().'/plugins/greensock/TweenMax.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('greensockTime', get_template_directory_uri().'/plugins/greensock/TimelineMax.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('scroll', get_template_directory_uri().'/plugins/scrollmagic/ScrollMagic.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('greensockAnimate', get_template_directory_uri().'/plugins/greensock/animation.gsap.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('greensock', get_template_directory_uri().'/plugins/greensock/ScrollToPlugin.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('owlCarousel', get_template_directory_uri().'/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri().'/plugins/easing/easing.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('video', get_template_directory_uri().'/plugins/video-js/video.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('youTube', get_template_directory_uri().'/plugins/video-js/Youtube.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('parallex', get_template_directory_uri().'/plugins/parallax-js-master/parallax.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('myJs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('newJs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/new.js', array(), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script_enqueue');
```

While I was searching for the solution in the internet I found that I need to set viewport inside my head. I tried keeping all of the following hoping that it will fix the issue but, it didn't.

ViewPort:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Recently, I tried keeping my styling code inside the `<style>` but that too didn't work. Is there anything that have connection with mobile friendly websites apart from viewport? What am I missing in my code?

**Update:** The code of media query works if I include the code between the `<head>` tag in `<style>`. If I view the source code I get all of my files `responsive.css, news_responsive.css` being loaded but I don't understand why the does not work if I linked the file where the css has written.

Comment: Hi Lenna, we need a bit more details than just "so worse." You shouldn't expect people to browse your site and do a full QA for you. Please save everyone's time and be more explicit about the kind of issues you're seeing on your site so we can help you out with those.

Comment: @cabrerahector I am really sorry for the incomplete question. I have added some clarification. I hope that will help to answer my question.

Comment: I checked your site and it appears that at least Bootstrap's media queries are working. I also had a look at the two additional stylesheets your site's homepage loads (`news.css` and `main_styles.css`) but none of them have @media queries in them, so where exactly are the ones you wrote?

Comment: @cabrerahector there is another file for media query and that is responsive.css. I just checked because I thought that I may have forget to link that file, but that has been linked too.

Comment: I guess you managed to fix whatever what's broken/not working as the site seems to be working as expected now (and the `responsive.css` stylesheet you mentioned is now being loaded as well, it wasn't when I checked earlier). What was it?

Comment: @cabrerahector The file `responsive.css` was there from the beginning but I just copied all the codes mentioned in the `responsive.css` to `main_style.css`. But, doing that didn't solve my problem. I am still getting the same layout like before even after I clearing the cache.

Comment: @cabrerahector Are you sure the mobile version is working fine in your mobile device?

Comment: It was working before. Now, after reading your comment, I checked again and it's all broken up.

Comment: @cabrerahector It has never worked from my end and I still don't know what is wrong in my code.